# Stuck in a loop when using $scope.on('$stateChangeStart')

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Before a user navigates away from the current state I want to prompt them to save their work. I've got a listener on `$stateChangeStart` but the problem is, after the user has confirmed their desire to leave the current state they get prompted again and can't leave because the listener keeps intercepting the state change. I tried passing a boolean parameter through so I could check if they confirmed their intent to leave, but it doesn't come through.

```
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
            console.log('toState: ');
            console.log(toState);
            console.log('toParams: ');
            console.log(toParams);
            console.log('fromState: ');
            console.log(fromState);
            console.log('fromParams: ');
            console.log(fromParams);
            console.log('options: ');
            console.log(options);

            //if (!isExitConfirmed) {
                event.preventDefault();
                ModalFactory.OpenTwoActionModal('EventFooterTwoActionModal',
                    'Exit Event', 'Are you sure you want to exit? Any unsaved changes will be lost.',
                    'Exit', function() { $state.go(toState, { isExitConfirmed: true }); },
                    'Cancel', function() {});
            //}
        });
```

I've logged to the console `toState`, `toParams`, `fromState`, `fromParams` and `options` but none of them contain `isExitConfirmed`.

What am I missing here, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @Ronnie You don't get re-prompted which is good. But it also doesn't transition states. The loading bar appears and finishes, the URL changes in the address bar, but the page doesn't actually change.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use resolve in state providers configuration instead of listening to the event. Event handlers are always not good practice to use because it causes memory leak.

Before you call stage.go(), invoke a popup for saving the data. once user confirms it, save the flag. Access the flag in resolve of next route change in state provider configuration.

Comment: This is not practical because the nav bar is available always and everywhere. I only want this prompt to appear when they change from this one specific state to any other state. So I want to listen to `$stateChangeStart` in my specific state to intercept transitions away from it. In all other cases I don't want this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use deferred objects from the $q service, and the related promises.
Promises can be consumed only once, and they can be resolved or rejected.